# Undefined is not a function whenever I try to create a new react function

Tags: android, react-native

I installed `react-native-installed-packages`. It is working fine out of the box. However I want to modify it by adding some extra methods that I can use in my JS. Here is what I have done.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, I have added a new public method, but whenever I am trying to call it from JS , I get the following error

`undefined is not a function (evaluating 'InstalledApps.removeApp(myappPackageID)')`

**Edit 1**

This is how I am using it in my JS

First I am importing the module

```
var InstalledApps = require('react-native-installed-packages');
```

and then I am calling the function as such

```
let val = InstalledApps.removeApp(myappPackageID);
```

My RNInstalledAppsPackage looks like this

**Edit 2**

```
package com.reactlibrary;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
public class RNInstalledAppsPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new RNInstalledAppsModule(reactContext));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks

Comment: did you already add `removeApp` in `RNInstalledAppsPackage`?

Comment: @flix - Sorry I am getting started with react-native. Can you please let me know where I should be adding it in my RNInstalledAppsPackage ?  I referenced other modules that I have and most of them have the same thing that.I have already.

Comment: sorry, my bad about the comment above, but I've an experience about creating my own module to work with react native, could you add the `JS` code how do you use `removeApp`?

Comment: @flix - updated , please see the section under Edit 1 - Thanks once again !

Comment: did you already re-install the apk after you adding your custom function? or maybe you are just using `reload` from react native menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your method in JS interface as well and try rebuild.
JS interface file is "rn-installed-apps/index.js".
This is the url :
https://github.com/jstokes/rn-installed-apps/blob/master/index.js

Comment: didn't think index.js can handle this too, all I have did just using bridge and use `NativeModules` from react native component, rofl